# Interpreting notation.

Tags: calculus

I have a problem in which I am suppose to sketch a function which is continuous on the interval of negative infinity to positive infinite. It has the following properties.

$f(-8)=f(-2)=f'(-8)=f'(-5)=f'(-2)=0$ ,    $f(x)$ is greater than or equal to $0$ on the interval of negative infinity to positive infinity.

The book I have never uses this notation so I'm stuck on the homework, which does use this notation. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: What's your problem, the chain of equalities? That means every one of these values is $0$. $a = b = c = d$ means $a = b$ __and__ $b = c$ __and__ $c = d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I'm guessing you've heard of the derivative of $f(x)$, which is defined as

$$\frac{d}{{dx}}f\left( x \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\Delta \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {x + \Delta } \right) - f\left( x \right)}}{\Delta }$$
This notation is cool because it shows you how there is an infinitely small change in y and an infinitely small change in x, and how the derivative is really slope. This is what dy and dx really mean, and remembering that $y=f(x)$, $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}$.

However, you can also use an alternative definition of the derivative, where $f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$. This is useful because 1. it's easier to write and 2. it makes writing multiple derivatives (aka the derivative of the derivative, and the derivative of the derivative of the derivative) much easier.

Remember now that the derivative is the slope, so your function will contain the following points: ($0,-2$); ($0,-8$). This starts a function but still really sucks, and we can make it better.

There's this thing called the "extreme value theorem" (google it) which basically says that the derivative of any maxima of a function is going to be 0. This means that the tangent line drawn the top of every hill and the bottom of every valley is going to be 0. This means that the function at $(0,-8);(0,-5);(0,-2)$; will all have a slope of $0$. I would recommend that you look deeper into this theorem.